# Compare two tables and retrieve data

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have 2 tables in SQL Server and I want to compare them. I want to take **'NEEDED_AMOUNT'** and '**min. 'ID'**. I tried the following:

```
SELECT S_ID, NEEDED_AMOUNT, ID
FROM (
    select T1.S_ID
        , T2.NEEDED_AMOUNT
        , T1.ID
    from T1
    INNER JOIN T2 MSD ON T1.S_ID = T2.S_ID
) TABLE1
GROUP BY S_ID, NEEDED_AMOUNT, ID
```

To explain this for example: in T1 table I have S_ID as '1' and its amount '20' and '30'. Also in T2 I have request for S_ID and I need '40' amount. So in T1 table how can I reach 40? I must take first row '20' amount and I split second row '30' to '20'. Below you can see what I want the output.

So here are the tables.

I can call this table T1 (ID is primary key and auto inc.):

```
ID  AMOUNT    S_ID
1      20       1
2      30       1
3      10       2
4      20       3
5      5        3
```

and I can call this table T2:

```
S_ID  NEEDED_AMOUNT    DATE
1      40              01.01.2020
2      5               02.01.2020
3      20              03.01.2020
```

So **my output** will be like this:

```
S_ID  NEEDED_AMOUNT  ID
1      20            1
1      20            2
2      5             3
3      20            4
```

Thanks for any opinion

Comment: Please don't re-post a duplicate of a closed question... it was closed because it was missing details or clarity, since nothing has changed its just going to get closed again.

Comment: I changed something after closed but it didn't open. So it says post new one.

Comment: Its takes time to re-open - multiple people need to review it to see whether its been improved enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would use recursive approach for this :

```
with cte as (
     select id, amount, s_id, needed_amount, 
            (case when amount = needed_amount then 1 else cnt end) as cnt
     from (select t1.*, t2.needed_amount, 
                  row_number() over (partition by t1.s_id order by t1.id) as seq,
                  count(*) over (partition by t1.s_id) as cnt
           from t1 inner join
                t2
                on t2.s_id = t1.s_id
          ) t
     where seq = 1
), cte1 as (
   select c.needed_amount / c.cnt as amount, c.s_id, 1 as start, c.cnt
   from cte c
   union all
   select amount, s_id, start + 1, cnt
   from cte1 c1
   where start < cnt
)
select s_id, amount, row_number() over (order by s_id) as id
from cte1;
```

Comment: when I added more row to T1 table, it's not working, sorry. I'm sharing the link what I tried. [Sql Vorn](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xDpdy6sS8t/)

Comment: @Vorn. . . With the above sample data what result do you want ? because i see as per question this  would do what you want.